# How to draw coords (lat,lon) in a Canvas and zoom it to show only coords closer than 50 meters?

Tags: android, canvas, gps, paint, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to represent an ArrayList of latitudes and longitudes into a canvas, but I only want to show those points closer than 50 meters of a given latitude and longitude. My canvas is 240dp width and 240 height. getWidth() and getHeight() gives to me 600x600 px, so I want to represent my location in the middle of the canvas and a point which has a distance from me of 50 meters just in the border of the canvas.

My main problem is that I don't know how to transform lat,lon into points x,y and tell to canvas that its area covers a radius of 50 meters.

My coords are: *PointF me = new PointF(lon, lat);*

Other people coord: *ArrayList people = new ArrayList();*

So I pretend canvas area shows, from a given location in the middle of the canvas, a scope of 50 meters, like the radius.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do it that way.  You'd loop over the list of points you may want to display, and check how far they are.  THen you'd see how far they are from you.  Those that are close enough you'd then convert the lat/long into x/y and draw onto the canvas.  You wouldn't tell the canvas how big it is in meters or what the center is, the canvas is a drawing concept and knows nothing about latitude or longitude.  It only knows pixels and drawing commands.